# Weird Timing Issue using time.time()

Tags: python, time, timing

When I run this code:

```
t0time = time.time() 

print 2**100000 #hundred thousand

t1time = time.time() 
print (t1time - t0time)*1000,"ms"
```

and this code:

```
t0time = time.time() 

print 2**1000000 #million

t1time = time.time() 
print (t1time - t0time)*1000,"ms"
```

They output 
    70.0349807739 ms
    6865.22507668 ms
respectively. But when I don't print the values, replacing the `print x` lines with `a = x`, I get the same output,
    0.00119209289551 ms 
for both, although they take obviously different times. Why is this?

Comment: `2**100000` has `30103` digits while `2**1000000` has `301030` digits, i.e. ten times the digits of the first. Your timings provide a confirmation of this. I don't see why you think that is strange.

Comment: What? I don't think that's strange, that has nothing to do with my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to check how much time a simple expression take is to use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). This is especially convenient with [IPython](http://ipython.org/):

```
In [6]: %timeit 2**100000
100000000 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ns per loop

In [7]: %timeit 2**1000000
100000000 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ns per loop

In [8]: %timeit 2**100000000
100000000 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ns per loop
Compiler time: 0.64 s
```

Notice how the time taken is constant (`16.4` *nanoseconds*. that's the time it takes to load whatever constant into the stack). However note how the last statement shows a `Compiler time: 0.64s`. So, as already have observed, the computation is performed by the compiler, not at runtime. In the last example the number is so big that the compilation time is significant and thus IPython displays it too.

If we try an even bigger number you see that the compiler time is the only one that changes significantly:

```
In [9]: %timeit 2**1000000000
100000000 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ns per loop
Compiler time: 8.62 s
```

We can have an other confirmation of what's happening looking directly at the bytecode that the compiler generates using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module:

```
In [10]: import dis
    ...: dis.dis(lambda: 2**100000)
    ...: 
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (999002093014384507944032764330033590  ... MANY more digits ... 396223208402597025155304734389883109376) 
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see the code does *not* contain any `BINARY_POWER` operator which would compute the result. The timings we have did with `timeit` are simply timing the `LOAD_CONST` operation, which takes the same time, independently of the size of the number.

If we try to disassemble a program that uses an argument we *do* get the computation at run-time:

```
In [12]: dis.dis(lambda x: x**2)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2) 
              6 BINARY_POWER         
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

This optimization is performed by the peephole optimizer and only works with *constants*. Even code simply as:

```
In [13]: def function():
    ...:     a = 2
    ...:     return a ** 100000
```

Is *not* optimized, although it seems perfectly equivalent to using `return 2 ** 100000`:

```
In [14]: dis.dis(function)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2) 
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a) 

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a) 
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (100000) 
             12 BINARY_POWER         
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Also note that *printing* a number takes time proportional to its size! `2**100000` has about 30k digits, while `2**1000000` has about 300k digits! Printing the latter takes about 10 times the time take to print the former (and your timings *do* confirm this!).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I don't know much about compiling and stuff, but thank you very much for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't print, it goes *very* fast. 0.00119209289551 ms is the smallest 'tick' that time.time() can catch.

So both report 0.00119209289551 ms.

To get an accurate estimate of speed. Time them over 100,000 loops and compare the total times.

Now if it *seems* like it takes longer, for example if you count of the time on your own, then here is what is probably happening:

Python is seeing the value 2**1000000 and saying "hey, that isn't using a variable or anything, so I can pre-calculate that before the code 'runs'." A lot of languages do that, they will convert things like 3*5 into 15, because, hey, why not? Might as well save computing power.

So the time your are waiting is time that python is spending 'pre-calculating' the values *before* your program runs. t0time isn't set because the script isn't running yet. I'm not a python expert, but this is how a lot of languages, both scripted and compiled, do things.

Comment: But it takes longer to do a = 2**1000000 than a = 2**100000, without printing it.

Comment: No, it takes longer to compile the code, execution takes the same time. I'll update my answer to explain.

Comment: The large amount of time taken when you print is the I/O on the precompiled amount

Comment: @user1188752 It might depend on the python version. Maybe old versions didn't fold all constants into the bytecode. AFAIK in python2.6+ and python3+ the time take is exactly the same because the computation is performed during compilation.